# Is there a way to populate np select conditions from a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Consider a lookup table like this:

```
   lower_bound upper_bound category
0       3          6         A
1       10         40        B
2       80         200       C
3       350        600       D
4       900        1500      E
```

Then, there is a DataFrame of elements that we need to classify based on the above conditions:

```
    id    value
0  id_1     20
1  id_2    500
2  id_3   1000
```

Each of these items would be classified according to their value, which should be between one of the specified ranges that exist in the lookup table. So:

```
    id   value  category
0  id_1    20       B
1  id_2    500      D
2  id_3    1000     E
```

I have tried the following, which works:

```py
conditions = []
choices = []
for condition in lookup_df.to_dict('records'):
    conditions.append(
        (df['value'].between(condition['lower_bound'], condition['upper_bound']))
    )
    choices.append(condition['category'])
```

And afterwards:

```py
df['category'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default=np.nan)
```

Is there a way to generate the conditions without converting to dict and looping the lookup DataFrame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.dot`:

```
vals = np.vstack(df['value'].values)
lb = condition['lower_bound'].values <= vals
ub = vals <= condition['upper_bound'].values
df['category'] = np.dot(lb & ub, condition['category'])
```

Output:

| id | value | category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id_1 | 20 | B |
| id_2 | 500 | D |
| id_3 | 1000 | E |

Comment: `dot` is very nice; good to see you back :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use numpy broadcasting. The idea is to create a boolean mask that returns True for the range each "value" falls into in `lookup_df`. Then select the matching values using boolean indexing.

```py
vals = df['value'].to_numpy()
msk = (lookup_df[['lower_bound']].to_numpy() < vals) & (vals < lookup_df[['upper_bound']].to_numpy())
df['category'] = lookup_df[['category']].to_numpy().repeat(len(df), axis=1)[msk]
```

Output:

```py
     id  value category
0  id_1     20        B
1  id_2    500        D
2  id_3   1000        E
```

If you want NaN values for values outside any range, `dot` product would work best here (this is exactly the same as [@Corralien's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72176686/17521785)):

```py
vals = df[['value']].to_numpy()
msk = (lookup_df['lower_bound'].to_numpy() < vals) & (vals < lookup_df['upper_bound'].to_numpy())
df = df.assign(category=msk.dot(lookup_df['category'])).replace('', float('nan'))
```

Comment: I really like this approach. One question though: what would happen if an item could not be classified (i.e. does not lie between any boundaries)? I think it would be omittted instead of being assigned a nan category or something like this.

Comment: @Ethelom That's right. In that case, `np.dot` would work best here.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `pd.merge_asof`:

```
output = pd.merge_asof(df, lookup_df[["lower_bound","category"]], left_on="value", right_on="lower_bound").drop("lower_bound", axis=1)

>>> output
     id  value category
0  id_1     20        B
1  id_2    500        D
2  id_3   1000        E
```